# Run two pod in the same node?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to tightly couple the two pods to run on the same node so that even if one pod is accidentally deleted, it gets rescheduled to the same node where another app resides. This should be the same for both apps.
Suppose, I have two pods P1 and P2. Then if the pod P1 is running on the node N1 then the pod P2 also should run on the same node N1.
I have implemented this using this manifest.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: first-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: first-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: first-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: first-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: image1
      nodeSelector:
        nodegroup: etl
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
                - key: "app"
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - first-app
```

and for the second app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: second-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: second-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: second-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: second-app
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: image1
      nodeSelector:
        nodegroup: etl
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
                - key: "app"
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - second-app
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - first-app
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

By this, second-app will always be assigned to the same node where the first-node is running. Now, when both the apps are running, first-app is accidentally removed from the node and assigned to another node, the second node should also evict from the node and assigned to another node where the first app runs.

Another solution might be, when the first-app is out from the node, it gets scheduled to same node where the second-app is running and vice-versa.

But I am not sure how to implement this?

Comment: While I echo Software Engineer below that this is a bad requirement and a sign that your software is already broken by design, you might want to look at running as two containers in a single pod instead.

Answer (score 2):

From a service perspective, this is a strange requirement, and as such, you may not be doing the right thing. It violates some of the fundamental ideas of service-oriented architecture where the level of abstraction is the service, and the 'stuff' underneath is all automated and we're not supposed to care about it. You may actually want to wire all of the containers from both pods in a single new pod to significantly simplify this problem. However...

There are a number of ways to achieve this, but the simplest may be with labels. I'll leave the implementation to you, but basically you can have an init container in both pods label the node, and have the deployment for both pods select the node with the label (`nodeSelector` in your yaml). Removing the label when both pods die can be a little more complicated, but still isn't too hard and may not even be necessary.

Another way is to use a mutating web hook (an admission controller) to find the node the other pod is running on and inject the `nodeName` property into your pod descriptor. This is also hard, but it means that you don't have to worry about cleaning up labels.

There are other techniques you could use, such as building a simple operator that keeps these things together, but these things tend to get complicated quickly. I'd strongly advise you to take another look at your requirement before doing any of this. It's probably more complicated than you think, because pods are often automatically scheduled to another node or scaled to multiple nodes, making the whole thing a headache.

Comment: All the devs I work with regularly write dockerized CLI tools to avoid dependency hell. It's completely natural and normal to call a CLI program from another program and give it the path to a folder on the same machine. Kubernetes decided to stop allowing direct docker.sock access so I'm supposed to use k8s jobs to run dockerzied cli tools, but they need access to the same folder. I don't see how these requirements are that strange

Comment: It's normal to pipe info between cli tools, yeah, of course, but in k8s it's far from normal to be doing that on a node's file system. You should be doing that via a pv/c. That way, you don't have the hassle of having to schedule the jobs on the same node as per this request.

Comment: and both bods can write to that pv/c? Another problem I have is the previous devops engineer decided to use EBS volumes for everything instead of pv/c. So, having sooo many things I have to change, I really need an example where someone else is doing this, but instead I'm getting a million puzzle pieces I have to piece together, yet all the devops people act like I should already know this stuff

Comment: Yeah, if you grant them the right permissions via the pvc. And I get your frustration, which is partially caused by the rapid evolution of kubernetes -- there's lots of advice online, but most of it is outdated. Use a google search filter to only find results from the past year when looking for help. 

You

Answer (score 1):

`requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` changing this to `requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution` will evict second app when first app gets removed from a node. But this feature is not yet implemented. So I think the option here is to write a custom scheduler which implements this.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/

Comment: But I think this is not yet supported by the kuberentes. 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity

Comment: You are right...write a custom scheduler which implements this

Comment: This is why the option names are so long, so you 100% have to type and see the `IgnoredDuringExecution` part.